# Unable to get my menu button to show the menu on click (using inline JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, onclick

this is the html

```
<script>
    var = navLinks = Document.getElementById(navLinks);

    function showMenu(){
        navLinks.style.right = "0";
    }
    function hideMenu(){
        navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
    }

</script>
```

this is the css

```
    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
        background: red;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 200px;
        top: 0;
        right: -200px;
        text-align: left;
        z-index: 2;
        transition: 1s;
```

I am not sure why when onclick nothing happens, to my knowledge ive done the JS correctly.

further up in the html I have this

```
<i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
```

and

```
<div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
                <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code from this

```
<script>
    var = navLinks = Document.getElementById(navLinks);

    function showMenu(){
        navLinks.style.right = "0";
    }
    function hideMenu(){
        navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
    }

</script>
```

to,

```
<script>
    var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");

    function showMenu(){
        navLinks.style.right = "0";
    }
    function hideMenu(){
        navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
    }

</script>
```

Comment: That did the trick, may I ask what the problem was? So I dont run into it again?

Comment: was it just the capitalisation?

Comment: We use camelCase in JavaScript. So "Document" is a function and "document" is an object. Also declaring the variable was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

"Document" must be "document" and navLinks must be string type

var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");

Comment: You should consider explaining the reasoning behind your answer, so then OP has a better idea of what to do next time should they encounter a similar problem.